# Can I update a Redis key value without changing the remaining TTL in JAVA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using `ValueOperations<K,V>` from `RedisTemplate<K,V>`. I just want to update an existing key without affecting its remaining time to live.
What is the best practice for doing so? Please guide me.

Comment: Since Redis 6.0, you can set the value with KEEPTTL option.

Comment: how can we use that programmatically in JAVA?